# DialogFlow: Posting attchment to Facebook via Fullfillment via Firebase (inline) Cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I am setting up a Chatbot for my Facebook page with Google Dialogflow handling the conversations.

For a specific Intent, I need to send 2 responses.

1. A regular statement with User's name put in.
2. A Persistent menu with 3 buttons

I understand that for a single Intent, I can't send the first response via Fulfillment code and the 2nd response setup through Dialogflow console UI. Hence, I need to write code to send both the responses.

I am able to send the first Response. But couldn't get to send a Rich message content. The DialogFlow documents show snippets of code, but it is unclear how the snippets of code from different pages fit it.

Here is my code (just posting actionHandlers) in an attempt to send a statement and an Audio (https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages#custom_payload)

```
const actionHandlers = {
    'input.welcome': () => {

        const speechText = 'Hi ' + userProfile['first_name'] + ', This is Eva, digital assistant of LMES Academy. Since my people are busy working on the content for the next video, I\'d like to help you with your needs ';
        const responsePayload = {
            'speech': speechText,
            'outputContexts': [{
                'user-name': userProfile.first_name 
            }],
            "data": {
                "facebook": {
                    "attachment": {
                        "type": "audio",
                        "payload": {
                            "url": "http://incompetech.com/music/royalty-free/mp3-royaltyfree/Funk%20Game%20Loop.mp3"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        sendResponse(responsePayload);
    },

    // The default fallback intent has been matched, try to recover (https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#fallback_intents)
    'input.unknown': () => {
        sendResponse('I\'m having trouble, can you try that again?'); // Send simple response to user
    }

};
```

The text response is working but the `Audio` is not. Am I doing the right way? Any help appreciated.

**Update 1:** Audio is working, after changing the mp3 link. But text response is not working.

Log of the object that is sent to `response.json()` in my Cloud function.

```
{
    "speech": "Hi Saiyasodharan, This is Eva, digital assistant of LMES Academy. Since my people are busy working on the content for the next video, I'd like to help you with your needs ",
    "displayText": "Hi Saiyasodharan, This is Eva, digital assistant of LMES Academy. Since my people are busy working on the content for the next video, I'd like to help you with your needs ",
    "data": {
        "facebook": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "audio",
                "payload": {
                    "url": "http://66.90.93.122/ost/death-note-original-soundtrack/bowkqzxs/01%20Death%20note.mp3"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "contextOut": [{
        "user-name": "Saiyasodharan"
    }]
}
```

In above code, I expect

- `displayText` to be displayed immediately -> which is not working
- `audio` response to happen -> This is now working, after changing the mp3 link

I believe I need to give the text response, audio response via `data` property. Let me try and update here.

Comment: You Dialogflow code looks correct.  Have you tried just sending the payload to Facebook Messenger to make sure the URL can be read by Facebook?

Comment: @matthewayne Updating more details in my Question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a payload for a given integration, the text of the response will be ignored.  You'll need to add your message with the attribute `text` to the `facebook` payload for it to be surfaced in Facebook messenger.  For example:

```
{
  "contextOut": [
    {
      "user-name": "Saiyasodharan"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "facebook": {
      "attachment": {
        "payload": {
          "url": "http://66.90.93.122/ost/death-note-original-soundtrack/bowkqzxs/01%20Death%20note.mp3"
        },
        "type": "audio"
      },
      "text": "Hi Saiyasodharan, This is Eva, digital assistant of LMES Academy. Since my people are busy working on the content for the next video, I'd like to help you with your needs "
    }
  },
  "displayText": "Hi Saiyasodharan, This is Eva, digital assistant of LMES Academy. Since my people are busy working on the content for the next video, I'd like to help you with your needs ",
  "speech": "Hi Saiyasodharan, This is Eva, digital assistant of LMES Academy. Since my people are busy working on the content for the next video, I'd like to help you with your needs "
}
```